# Java searching for a substring URL in a string URL

Tags: java, string, comparison, string-comparison, apache-stringutils

I have a couple of URLs:

```
a. https://iamterribleatthis/a

b. https://iamterribleatthis/a/index.html
```

I'm using Apache stringutls to see if 'a' is present in 'b' but I think that the forward slash is failing the comparison. Is there an easier/better way to find if 'a' is present in 'b' including the forward slash? Thanks.

Comment: Showing your code might be helpful. Ideally forward slash shouldn't create any issue here. But why do you need `Apache StringUtils` class, rather than just using `String#contains()` method?

Comment: Do you want to find, if 'b' includes 'a' ? or longest matching substring ?

Comment: @RohitJain Thank you. It appeared like '/' was causing a problem but when I checked my code I found out a typo that was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String a = "https://iamterribleatthis/a";
    String b = "https://iamterribleatthis/a/index.html";

    System.out.println(b.contains(a));
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the URL to his external form and use `indexOf()`:

```
b.toExternalForm().indexOf(a.toExternalForm())
```

if the return value is bigger than -1 a is a part of b